# SonarQube build failure for .NET Core 2.0

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I'm trying to use SonarQube (6.2) to build .NET Core 2.0 project. I'm getting the following error:
"The SonarQube MSBuild integration failed: SonarQube was unable to collect the required information about your projects."
In fact, I use **Bash script step** (instead of standard .NET Core build) in the pipeline, as it is more convenient, when working with Docker containers deployed on Linux.
Is there any clue how I can overcome this issue in this case?

Comment: SonarQube is not building you project. How do you connect to the SonarQube instance? Do you use a valid token and has the user analyze rights?

Comment: Which SonarQube Scanner are you using ? .Net analysis (e.g. [SonarC#](https://docs.sonarqube.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=1441900) ) requires the [Scanner for MSBuild](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+MSBuild) which requires Windows OS.

Comment: These are valid points guys. SQ connects to the instance well through the relevant endpoint, so it's not the issue. In fact, the agents are run on the Linux machine that builds a .NET Core project.

Comment: As @Nicolas B. correctly pointed out, SQ for MSBuild step won't help in this case, so I had to use SonarQube Scanner CLI.  Can't find a clear guidance on how to use this particular step with .NET Core and having in mind that I build the code in Docker .yml